# How to create a VS Code snippet which toggles a line prefix

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a VS Code snippet which can toggle the character sequence `// ?` at the start of the current line.
When I run it, i want a line such as this:

```
var x = 10
```

to turn into:

```
// ?var x = 10
```

and visa versa.

This is similar to the built in comment toggling functionality (Cmd + /), but with a custom prefix.

Comment: What language is this for?

Comment: I use JS but this is more of general VS Code question...

Comment: There is a way to modify which comment characters are used for any language.  This way would give you the toggling ability you want.  There is no general way to do this in vscode without an extension.  Do you still want to see the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 approaches to consider.

1. Modify which comment characters are used for the languages you are interested in.  Using an extension I wrote, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax), this is very easy to do.  A quick demo:

[image: demo toggling custom comments with extension]

The advantages of this are it is very easy to set up and as you can see you can toggle multiple lines easily because the built-in commands `Toggle Line Comment` (`editor.action.commentLine`) or `Add Line Comment` (`editor.action.addCommentLine`) use the setting you created.  This means whenever you use such commands they will do what you want.  So you could use a line comment command in a macro and it would just work.  Demo that shows copying the current line down and commenting the original line:

[image: macro comment and duplicate line down]

The above demo uses this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
      "cursorUp",
      "editor.action.addCommentLine",  // uses your comment characters from the setting above
      "cursorDown"        
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

---

2. Just make a snippet/keybinding that will toggle those prefix characters on and off.  This can be done with a single keybinding that uses the regex to detect whether those prefix characters are there (if so, remove them) or are not there (if so, add them):

```json
 {
    "key": "ctrl+/",       // whatever keybinding you want, acts as a toggle
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { 
     "commands": 
       [
         "cursorEnd",             // so cursor stays on same line
         "cursorHomeSelect",
         {
           "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
           "args": { 

             "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(\\/\\/ \\?)(.+)|(.+)/$2${3:+\/\/ ?}$3/}"
           }
         }
       ]
   },
   // "when": "editorLangId == javascript || editorLangId == typescript"
   "when": "resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js|ts|r)(?!on)/"
 }
```

The regex `(\\/\\/ \\?)(.+)|(.+)` puts the prefix characters into capture group 1 (if they exist) and the rest of the line into either capture group 2 or 3 (only one of which will be defined).

Capture group 1 is actually never used so the prefix characters don't need to be in a capture group but the separation in the regex helps to understand what is going on.  The regex will only populate capture group 2 if there are those prefix characters.  And since we never add `$1` to the transform group 1 is effectively removed if it ever existed.

The transform part of the snippet: `$2${3:+\/\/ ?}$3` will insert group 2 (which may be empty), then **IF** there is a group 3 (there will only be a group 3 if there were no prefix characters on the line) and then add group 3 (the rest of the line).  The regex has an alternation or `|` so only one of groups 2 and 3 will ever have content - there is no problem putting a reference to an empty capture group in the transform.

A demo of this second approach would be the same as the first demo but the multiple line commenting wouldn't work (only the first line would be commented).  And the various line comment commands like `Toggle Line Comment` and `Add Line Comment`  wouldn't use those prefix characters.  But maybe that is what you want and so method (2) would be better for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually needed the second approach because this doesn't replace regular comments, it just marks the comment so that I can style it differently using the Better Comments VS Code extension. 

This works like a charm with the added bonus of learning something new. Thank you again for the in-depth explanation and screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* simulate removal by first selecting the line, then inserting a snippet that refers to the [variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) for the selection (`TM_SELECTED_TEXT`) or current line's contents (`TM_CURRENT_LINE`) and does a [variable transform](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms). I wrote this example as a keybinding:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": { "commands": [{
        "command": "expandLineSelection",
    },{
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": { "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/\\/\\/ \\?(.*)/$1/}" },
    }]},
},
```

And making a snippet that inserts the comment prefix is also easy and can be done in a similar fashion to the above. But as far as I know, you can't make a set of keybinding to the same key that is smart enough to know when the comment prefix is there and remove it, and vice versa because I'm not aware of there being a context key for line content where the cursor is.

Comment: In `runCommands` you don't need the `{}` object structure for a command, like `expandLineSelection` that takes no arguments - see my answer.  It still works but isn't necessary.  Also see my answer for how to use the snippet regex to make a toggle - just set-up an alternation to detect presence or absence of those prefix characters and a conditional to add them when you need to.